# Detect or prevent Commons Net FTPClient from blocking on read

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm using the Commons Net `FTPClient` class to periodically poll an ftp site and attempt to download a file.  Occasionally the thread is blocking indefinitely when trying to read from the site and I wondered if anyone else had encountered this problem and could offer any workarounds?

I'm using `FTPClient`'s `retrieveFileStream(String)` method to get a handle to an InputStream, which I then attempt to read from.  Below is a partial stack trace of the blocked thread.

```
"FTP File Poll Thread" prio=10 tid=0x083b0800 nid=0x6324 runnable [0x65b5b000..0x65b5beb0]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
        - locked <0x5c851928> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
        at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:122)
        at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.__read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:75)
        at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:170)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
```

Comment: This is a much general problem, that of blocking I/O in Java, and the fact that there's no way to avoid it or to kill the thread.

Comment: That's what I thought :-(  I was hoping there was a non-blocking FTP client out there somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kludge I ended up using here was to schedule a task to raise an alert if the FTP operation took longer than X seconds.  I did actually find [javanioftp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javanioftp/) on Sourceforge but in my situation it doesn't warrant the development overhead in switching clients.

Answer (score 1):

java.io is blocking, you need to use the java.nio package. Never used ftp with java.nio, but assume it must work because http can work with java.nio.

Regards